# heart rate monitor

Tags: ros, bluetooth, rate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to connect a heart rate monitor device to the ROS by using the Bluetooth and stream the data.
Is there an available code for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191860/heart-rate-monitor/) by [Behzad](https://answers.ros.org/users/20126/behzad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please specify the device name and the bluetooth interface. If you can read the bluetooth stream data, you can publish it to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [feroze](https://answers.ros.org/users/6616/feroze/) with karma: 26 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1